# how can we use more than one class object attributes of one model in another model in Django

Tags: python, html, django, class, model

```
class Webpage(models.Model):
    topic=models.CharField()
    name=models.CharField(max_length=264,unique=True)
    url=models.URLField(unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.url,self.name


class AccessRecord(models.Model):
    name=models.ForeignKey(Webpage)
    date=models.DateField()
    urls=models.ForeignKey(Webpage)


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.date)
```

**how can i use "name and url" attribute of "Webpage" class in "AccessRecord" class**

Comment: Take a bit more time to explain. I do not understand. sorry

Answer (score 2):

Set a related name for both or at least to one of the Foreign Keys

```py
class AccessRecord(models.Model):
    name=models.ForeignKey(Webpage)
    date=models.DateField()
    urls=models.ForeignKey(Webpage, related_name='webpage')
```

here is the [usage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects) example:

```py
obj.webpage.all()
```

Comment: when i use related_name='webpage' it is returning self.name but i want urls = Webpage.url

Comment: can we return two fields in single django model

Comment: @PranayReddy when you use `ForeignKey()` for field in your model, you will save an `id` of the object you are referencing. The function `__str__()` is used to override default representation of the object in your django code or console (makes it easy to test), but in your `AccessRecord` table in your DB in column `urls` or `name` will be placed an `id` of object you are linking

Comment: @PranayReddy the technique of linking two foreign keys from same model using `related_name` is used when you want to link to _single_ `AccessRecord` object two _different_ objects from the same model, `Webpage` in your case

Comment: @PranayReddy let's say you have two `Webpage` objects: `google` & `facebook`, and you want to create an `AccessRecord` object. Using your current models structure, you will end up creating object like: `{id: 1, name: google, date: ..., urls: 'facebook.com'}` -- which seems to be complete absurd to me

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to save the incident that user accessed a certain page, you don't need to create two references to the model `Webpage` to save both `name` & `urls` to the `AccessRecord` object. Just create one `ForeignKey()`

```py
class AccessRecord(models.Model):
    webpage=models.ForeignKey(Webpage)
    date=models.DateField()
```

Then you can access `name`, `url` or any field of `Webpage` using dot notation

```py
web_obj = Webpage.objects.create(topic='lorem ipsum', name='google', url='google.com')
obj = AccessRecord.objects.create(webpage=web_obj, date=timezone.now())
obj.webpage.name    # <- will return you 'google'
obj.webpage.url     # <- will return you 'google.com'
obj.webpage.topic   # <- will return you 'lorem ipsum'
obj.date            # <- will return you date object created
```

You can also use double `_` notation when you use different `Model.objects` methods. Example of filtering access records by webpage url field

```py
all_google_accesses = AccessRecord.objects.filter(webpage__url='google.com')
```